# how to make user don't need to login again in android

Tags: android, authentication

I want to make a user don't need to login again, once after login. My code don't skip login page. How to skip login page? I have a start page. I press start button, it go to Login page. But a user have already login, make to skip the login page and go to next page.
How should I do?

```
 JSONObject json=null;
                        int status=2;
                        String userID=null;
                        String teamID=null;
                        String teamName=null;
                        String admin=null;
                        String backNo=null;
                        String userName=null;

                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",edit_txt_EmailAddress.getText().toString()));//// define the parameter
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",edit_txt_Password.getText().toString()));

                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                           .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
                           .penaltyLog().build());

                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> pp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        //postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID","396797666"));

                        String response = null;
                        try {
                              response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/kwikwi/login.php", postParameters);
                              json=new JSONObject(response);
                              userID=json.getString("userID");
                            }
                        catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         Log.i("USERID", userID+"");
                         JSONObject json_data = null;
                         String teamStatus ="";

                        String result = response.toString();
                        JSONObject jsonobj = null;
                        try{

                        jsonobj = new JSONObject (result);
                        teamStatus=jsonobj.getString("teamStatus");

                        }
                        catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        }

                        Log.i("TeamStatus", result+"");

                        Log.i("RESULT", teamStatus+"");
                        //Log.i("halo",teamStatus+"");

                        String[] teamSaving=new String[6];
                        String[] noteamSaving=new String[2];

                    if (blNagSetting == true){
                        if(teamStatus.equals("1")){
                            try {
                                Log.i("Team Kyaw Win tal","Log in ma twar buu.");

                                userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                                userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");
                                teamID=jsonobj.getString("teamID");
                                teamName=jsonobj.getString("teamName");
                                admin=jsonobj.getString("admin");
                                backNo=jsonobj.getString("backNo");

                                teamSaving[0]=userName;
                                teamSaving[1]=userID;
                                teamSaving[2]=teamID;
                                teamSaving[3]=teamName;
                                teamSaving[4]=admin;
                                teamSaving[5]=backNo;

                                Log.i("USerName", userName+"");
                                Log.i("UserID",userID+"");
                                Log.i("TeamId",teamID+"");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            Intent teamshi=new Intent(Login.this,Team.class);
                            teamshi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(teamshi);
                            finish();

                        }
                        else if(teamStatus.equals("0"))
                        {
                            try {

                                Log.i("NoTeam Kyaw Win tal","Log in ma twar buu.");
                                userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                                userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");

                                noteamSaving[0]=userName;
                                noteamSaving[1]=userID;

                                Log.i("USerNameNN", userName+"");
                                Log.i("UserIDNN",userID+"");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Intent noteamshi=new Intent(Login.this,NoTeam.class);
                            noteamshi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(noteamshi);
                            finish();
                        }

                    }else
                    {
                        if(teamStatus.equals("1")){
                            try {
                                Log.i("Team Win tal","Log in hmar");

                                userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                                userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");
                                teamID=jsonobj.getString("teamID");
                                teamName=jsonobj.getString("teamName");
                                admin=jsonobj.getString("admin");
                                backNo=jsonobj.getString("backNo");

                                teamSaving[0]=userName;
                                teamSaving[1]=userID;
                                teamSaving[2]=teamID;
                                teamSaving[3]=teamName;
                                teamSaving[4]=admin;
                                teamSaving[5]=backNo;

                                Log.i("USerName", userName+"");
                                Log.i("UserID",userID+"");
                                Log.i("TeamId",teamID+"");



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            editor = prefsNagSetting.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(NAG_SETTING, true);
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent teamshi=new Intent(Login.this,Team.class);
                            teamshi.putExtra("TeamSaving", teamSaving);
                            startActivity(teamshi);


                        }
                        else if(teamStatus.equals("0"))
                        {
                            try {
                                Log.i("noTeam Win tal","Log in hmar");

                                userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                                userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");

                                noteamSaving[0]=userName;
                                noteamSaving[1]=userID;

                                Log.i("USerNameNN", userName+"");
                                Log.i("UserIDNN",userID+"");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            editor = prefsNagSetting.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(NAG_SETTING, true);
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent noteamshi=new Intent(Login.this,NoTeam.class);
                            noteamshi.putExtra("NoTeamSaving", noteamSaving);
                            startActivity(noteamshi);

                        }
                        else{
                            showAlertDialog(Login.this,"Invalid Email and Password", "Enter Valid Email and Password", false);
                        }
                    }
                    }
```

Here is my code.

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            isInternetPresent = conDetector.isConnectingToInternet();
            Boolean save=false;

             if (isInternetPresent){
                    isLoggedIn();
                    saveLoggedIn(save);
                    if (isLoggedIn()){
                       Intent team= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Team.class);
                       startActivity(team);
                    }
                    else{

                    Intent goLogin=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
                    startActivity(goLogin);
                    }
             }
             else{
                 showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                            "You don't have internet connection.", false);
             }
        }
    });
}

private boolean isLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //The false represents the default value, if the variable is not stored
    boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
    return isLoggedIn;
}

private void saveLoggedIn(boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

That's my edit code.

Answer (score 3):

In your star activity, you should verify if the user has already logged in.

**How to know this?**

You will need a boolean variable to know. A persistent variable. So, when you create the start activity, you will put:

```
if (variable){
   goToLoggedActivity();
}else{
   goToLogInActivity();
}
```

When the user logs in, you will need to set this *variable* to **true**

When the user logs out, you will need to set this *variable* to **false**

**How to make it persistent?**

Look at these functions.

```
private boolean isLoggedIn() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //The false represents the default value, if the variable is not stored
        boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
        return isLoggedIn;
    }

    private void saveLoggedIn(boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

To Store the variable you just need to call this function above.

Another good way to make it you can see [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Comment: where do I put these sentence... At Login Page or Start Page.

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want to go to Logged page after the user clicks the button, you should put this in the page of the button.

Comment: Let me explain again. My start page has a button. When press it, it go to login page. but a user have already login, press the start button and it'll skip the login page. OK. Your first code will be at start button onClick, and next code is at login... Right?

Comment: So you should put these functions in Start Page and the condition in onClick of the button.

Comment: Please wait a while, I run my app. :)

Comment: yes, please. Did you debug to check if the variable is set correctly?

Comment: In your code you whould remove isLoggedIn(); and  saveLoggedIn(save); you should also remove the save definition. You are always setting it to false. You cannot do it. I hope NAG_SETTING means "isLoggedIn"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a conditional statement in your `LAUNCHER ACTIVITY`. Make it like a splash screen or something
That is you can store the username and password in your shared preference along with the `isRememeber=true/false`. and when the user starts the app,the splash screen activity can check if the `isRememeber` activity has been set true or false by the user and can start the `MainActivity` or the `LoginActivity`.

> Almost like this example here

```
Intent login=new Intent(Splashscreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
Intent Main=new Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class);
......................
//Checking the shared preference here and storing the isRemebered value to a variable
if(isRemembered)
startActivity(Main);
else
startActivity(login);
```

Hope this helped you,all you have to do is make an additional activity that has to be launched as the LAUNCHER activity for more info on splash screens go [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

Comment: I already used shared preference but I havn't seen isRemember that you say... And how about editor... if you know, tell me about that,plz.

Answer (score 0):

After user login save a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that the user logged in.

when the app starts if the user has that shared preference that means you can skip that activity and open the one you would after login.

Thing to consider - what if someone somehow fakes that SharedPreference? make sure it contains something that's validated against your server later to make sure that it was generated by a real login and wasn't faked (could even implement OAuth protocol).